# selenium chromedrive fails on collection

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("uname")).sendKeys("admin")
Dim list() As WebElement = driver.findElements(By.TagName("a"))
```

my project correctly executes the sendkeys command, so everything is good until the last line, just cannot get it to execute have tried for many hours and much googling whatever I try there is error, but the the first line always correct

Answer (score 0):

Try make it generic

```
list(of webElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of web element in **Java**:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.TagName("a"));
```

Comment: how do i use java in visual basic?

Comment: Selenium doesnt support vb, check the list of supported languages: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/#client-drivers

Comment: You cant use it. Use one of the lang it supports. You can use it if you select java. Actually the first line of your code is also java or c# that's why I wrote the second as java.